# Choose provider of a Factory class

Tags: java, factory, tibco-business-works

I'm calling a method of a java class from my Tibco process. This class uses the DocumentBuilderFactroy abstract class.

```
DocumentBuilderFactroy documentBuilderFactroy = DocumentBuilderFactroy.neInstance ();
```

Everything works fine when I run the application locally in eclipse. But in deployed mode, I have the following error:

> Provider for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory can not be
>   created.

So I changed the way of instantiating the documentBuilderFactroy object in the code by specifying the implementation class.

```
String providerDBF = "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl";
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance (providerDBF, null);
```

My question is : How can I specify the implementation class to avoid the problem without hardcoding it?

I'm not using Maven.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory system property` or the `properties file` in the `JRE` directory.

From the [DocumentBuilderFactory documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html):

```
public static DocumentBuilderFactory newInstance()
```

> Obtain a new instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory. This static method
>   creates a new factory instance. This method uses the following ordered
>   lookup procedure to determine the DocumentBuilderFactory
>   implementation class to load:

- Use the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory system property.
- Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory.
  This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format
  and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class
  with the key being the system property defined above. The
  jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and
  it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not
  exist when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further
  attempts are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to
  change the value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been
  read for the first time.
- Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if
  available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for
  a classname in the file
  META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory in jars
  available to the runtime.
- Platform default DocumentBuilderFactory instance. Once an application
  has obtained a reference to a DocumentBuilderFactory it can use the
  factory to configure and obtain parser instances.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance--) states, where can it be set:

> This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine
>   the DocumentBuilderFactory implementation class to load:
>
> - Use the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory system property.
> - Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties
>     format and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation
>     class with the key being the system property defined above. The
>     jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and
>     it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist
>     when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts
>     are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the
>     value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been read for
>     the first time.
> - Uses the service-provider loading facilities, defined by the ServiceLoader class, to attempt to locate and load an implementation
>     of the service using the default loading mechanism: the
>     service-provider loading facility will use the current thread's
>     context class loader to attempt to load the service. If the context
>     class loader is null, the system class loader will be used.
> - Otherwise, the system-default implementation is returned.